# Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string' for folders found

Tags: c#

So i want to name of the folders printed found in my executable location.

```
var foldersFound = Directory.GetDirectories(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "test", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
Debug.Print(foldersFound);
```

However i get an error saying

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: do a foreach loop and print every item from the foldersFound array. The return type of GetDirectories is an array so you can not print that.

Comment: That seemed to work. Thanks!

Comment: posted that as an answer as well, please accept and glad to help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do a foreach loop and print every item from the foldersFound array. The return type of GetDirectories is an array so you can not print that.

Should look like this:

```
foreach(var folder in foldersFound){
   Debug.Print(folder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Directory.GetDirectories() returns a string array. If you want to print all of the directories then you need to enumerate them

```
var foldersFound = 
Directory.GetDirectories(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "test", SSearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (var folder in foldersFound)
    {
        Debug.Print(folder);
    }
```

Or you can use string.Join() to concatenate them

```
Debug.Print(string.Join(",",foldersFound));
```

Answer (score 0):

> What am i doing wrong?

`Debug.Print()` is expecting string type and not array of strings.

```
var foldersFound = 
Directory.GetDirectories(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "test", SSearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Is returning strings array. Just try to iterate the strings array and print one by one.